# React:: Error: GraphQL error: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

I deployed my app on netlify.

On local server, I could post a comment.

But in production mode,

> "Error: GraphQL error: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined"
>   appears when I submit my comment.

I tried many ways to fix this issue, but I could not solve it.

I think the problem is my GraphQL server on Heroku.

check-auth.js

```
const { AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { SECRET_KEY } = require('../config');

module.exports = (context) => {
  // context = { ... headers }
  const authHeader = context.req.headers.authorization;

  if (authHeader) {
    // Bearer ....
    const token = req.headers.authorization || '';
   //I tried. const token = req.headers["authorization"];
    if (token) {
      try {
        const user = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
        return user;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new AuthenticationError('Invalid/Expired token');
      }
    }
    throw new Error("Authentication token must be 'Bearer [token]");
  }
  throw new Error('Authorization header must be provided');
};
```

Only a logged in user can post a comment.

My user ID is stored in the local server, after a user logged in.
The key is jwtToken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely in  the way you are forwarding the request object in your Apollo server.  Make sure it reads something like this:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({req}),  // LIKE THIS
  context: ({ req }) => req,      // NOT LIKE THIS, Results in undefined req
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo or you actually missing the context object when you are fetching token?

```
const token = context.req.headers.authorization || '';
```

Check the above line in your code and why do u even need this when you already have that in authHeader constant.

And your token ideally will be inside context.req.headers['x-token'] or req.headers['token'] depends upon how you pass.